# Parallel upload of directory structure with small files to Amazon S3

Tags: mac, amazon-s3

How can I efficiently upload a big directory structure with many files to Amazon S3 from OSX? I would like to make parallel uploads.

Comment: What do you use to upload files to your Amazon S3 account currently?

Comment: Transmit and S3Fox

Comment: Transmit should already support this feature since its a FTP client.  Of course uploading multiple files at once won't really speed up the overal amount of time it takes to upload those files.